# Get the list of apps capable of handling the SEND intent to display in a View (not a popup dialog)

Tags: android, android-intent, share, send

I'm trying to get the list of all apps installed on a phone capable of handling the SEND intent. I am currently handling this situation by using Intent.createChooser but this is not what I am trying to achieve as I would like to be able to get access to the list of apps to display them in a View in my activity, in a way similar to how the Android stock Gallery app displays them and NOT in a spinner dialog.

Screenshot available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dQmo.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`, given an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` configured as you would use with `createChooser()` (i.e., has the MIME type, `Uri`, etc.). This will give you a list of all the matches that would appear in the chooser. You can then make use of the user's selection to launch the actual activity.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) that uses this to create a home screen-style launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to get specific action (in my case ACTION_SEND) from an Application and do something like putExtra("myMessage", shareMessage); so that the Share Action of that gets populated with my shareMessage. I could accomplish till getting the Application which can handle ACTION_SEND. Thank You

Comment: @Archie.bpgc: With regards to extras, see the documentation for `ACTION_SEND` for what is available and *possibly* supported. Each app with an activity that can respond to `ACTION_SEND` has its choice as to whether or not it will support any given extra. And since applications don't have actions -- activities do -- I do not understand the first part of your comment.

Comment: yeah, i mean Activity there, not Application. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Your source code actually helped alot. But it doesnt work exactlty like android's activity chooser dialog.

Comment: Actually I think your code does something wrong. You created an intent. Then use package manager to query activities for the intent. Then when you get component name; you create a totally new intent and try to launch it. What I did was modify the original intent with the newly got component name. Then launch it. Everything seems to be working accurately now. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan: So long as the `Intent` has the correct data in it, it does not matter how you create the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that is where I think you are wrong. For instance, my app only handles intent if it's action is ACTION_VIEW. Another app, I assume, might handle data differently based on the required action.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();

Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager()
    .queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
    packages.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
}
```